# Cannot access nginx url within container

Tags: nginx, vagrant, docker, graphite, vagrantfile

I have the following setup

1. Vagrant box with docker installed
2. Docker container up and running and working

However I cannot access from my host one of the urls specified in nginx config

I can access the grafana one

My vagrant file

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "dockerNoel"
    config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |virtualbox|
        # allocate 1024 mb RAM
        virtualbox.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"] 
        # allocate max 50% CPU
        virtualbox.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", "50"]
      end
    # we'll forward the port 8000 from the VM to the port 8000 on the host (OS X)
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 80, guest: 80
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8125, guest: 8125, protocol: 'udp'
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8126, guest: 8126
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 9200, guest: 9200
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 9300, guest: 9300

    config.vm.provision "docker"
end
```

my nginx config file

```
daemon off;
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  server_tokens off;

  server_names_hash_bucket_size 32;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location / {
      root /src/grafana;
      index index.html;
    }
    location /graphite/ {
        proxy_pass                 http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_set_header           X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header           Host  $host;

        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }

    location /elasticsearch/ {
        proxy_pass                 http://127.0.0.1:9200/;
        proxy_set_header           X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header           Host  $host;

        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }
  }

   server {
    listen 8888;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
     }

    location /static/ {
      include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
      default_type  application/octet-stream;
      root /cabot/;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 81 default_server;
    server_name _;

    open_log_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s min_uses=2 valid=1m;

    location / {
        proxy_pass                 http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header           X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header           Host  $host;

        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, authorization, accept";

    location /content {
      alias /var/lib/graphite/webapp/content;
    }

    location /media {
      alias /usr/share/pyshared/django/contrib/admin/media;
    }
  }
}
```

When I browse from host to `http://127.0.0.1` it works
But for `http://127.0.0.1/graphite/` I get 404 not found

When I use curl from within guest vagrant box they both work

I believe I am doing something silly regarding networking but cant figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You have an ending slash in your proxy_pass. This means `/graphite/` is passed to the backend. I suspect graphite is running from the root, so on the backend the uri is not found.

See the documentation on proxy_pass: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass